# Advice for custom listview with title

Tags: android, listview, layout

i want to add a custom listview with an title aboce the list. I found some hints but could fix my problem. So maybe someone here can give a clue:

my class (includes two more classes)

```
package com.droidfish.apps.acli;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListProduct2 extends Activity {
private static ArrayList<String> sProducts;
private static String[] sPro;
private Integer iType;

private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return sPro.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listitemdef);
            Log.d("Create item", sPro[position]);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(sPro[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listproducts);
    savedInstanceState = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    sProducts = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("aircrafts");
    sPro = (String[]) sProducts.toArray(new String[0]);
    iType = savedInstanceState.getInt("type");
    ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    TextView titleList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleProductList);
    TextView titleList2 = new TextView(this);
    titleList2.setText("Manufacturer");
    l1.addHeaderView(titleList2);
    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
```

(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , sPro));
    }

```
private static final String[] country = { "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia",
        "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Laos", "Latvia",
        "Lebanon", "Lesotho ", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania",
        "Luxembourg" };

}
```

my layout for listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleProductList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left|center"
android:paddingBottom="5px"
android:paddingLeft="5px"
android:paddingTop="5px" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listitemdef"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="hi"
    android:textColor="#FFFF00" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any advice is welcome

Comment: When you say title, do you mean a textview on top of the listview that does not scroll with the content of the listview?

Comment: well yes,... thats what i want. I thought just adding a textview above the listview but it didnt work. addHeaderView i didnt got to work as u can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem, you're not specifying the `orientation` attribute of your LinearLayout, and the default is horizontal. So the textview is being added to the *right* of your listview.  Also, the easiest way to create a title view is to use the layout_weight attribute. So, try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >  <!-- missing orientation-->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleProductList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title" />

  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" > <!-- weight attribute -->
</ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the addHeaderView method described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: actually i did as u can see, its at the end